# Javascript Regex "ends with" vs "does not end with"

Tags: javascript, regex

The following javascript renders the boolean to each statement's right:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^[\w\/].*result\b/);

console.log(reg.test('pathtofiletest')); -> false
console.log(reg.test('path/to/file/test')); -> false
console.log(reg.test('/path/to/file//test/result')); -> true
console.log(reg.test('/path/to/file/not_a_test$#%$5724')); -> false
```

Which is great! That's exactly what I want. Now I want to invert the ending statement. I want the other strings that **do not end in result** to be true, while the statement that **does end in result** to be false. But, I can't just negate that statement. I've tried:

```
^[\w\/].*^result\b
^[\w\/].*(?!result\b)
^[\w\/].*^(?!result\b)
^[\w\/].^(result\b)
```

among a ton of others. What am I missing?

**Application for those curious**

The reason I'm asking is because I'm using express with nodejs. I call

```
router.get('/pathstring', function (req, res, next) {
    //code
}
```

The pathstring is a regex expression. It is not simply true or false.

Comment: Can you just write `!reg.test(...)`?

Comment: no. see comment on @Zagrev's answer.

Comment: I marked georg's answer as correct as it __is__ the correct answer to this specific question. However, it still is not working with express's routing functionality so I'll have to ask another question to settle that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
^(?!.*result$).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/jO9fN6/1

Comment: $ can also be replaced with \b if it's not 1 per line.

Comment: This is pretty solid. It isn't working directly so I'll have to fiddle with it.Why the .* at the end after the parens?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just negate the result? Like:

```
!reg.test('pathtofiletest')
```

Comment: That is not what I'm trying to do. I'm using the regex in another application, not in an actual reg.test() function. I just didn't want to push away regex pros from answering if they aren't familiar with nodejs and express get requests.

Comment: ok, but the logic still stands. Instead of trying to create a inverse regexp, why not just create a function that returns the inverse result?  Name the function appropriately (like PathEndsInResult(...)).

Comment: Logic is solid. But again, that is not the application. I will update question with application at the end just to clarify.